# Why would someone define a abstract visitor class like this?

Tags: c++

This is just a minimal version of a bigger legacy code in a project where the visitor pattern is defined like:-

```
struct AbstractElement;
struct FirstElement;
struct SecondElement;
struct ThirdElement;

struct AbstractVisitor{
   virtual void visit(FirstElement&) = 0;
   virtual void visit(SecondElement&) = 0;
   virtual void visit(ThirdElement&) = 0;
};

struct AbstractElement{
   virtual void accept(AbstractVisitor* v) = 0;
};

struct FirstElement : public AbstractElement{
    void accept(AbstractVisitor* v) { v->visit(*this); }
}

struct SecondElement : public AbstractElement{
    void accept(AbstractVisitor* v) { v->visit(*this); }
};

struct ThirdElement : public AbstractElement{
    void accept(AbstractVisitor* v){ v->visit(*this); }
};

struct Visitor : public AbstractVisitor{
    void visit(FirstElement& p){ process(p); }
    void visit(SecondElement& p){ process(p); }
    void visit(ThirdElement& p){ process(p); }
    virtual void process(AbstractElement& b){/* some processing common to every concrete element */ }
};
```

The part of code which I couldn't understand is why the writer of this code has defined the AbstractVisitor class as:-

```
struct AbstractVisitor{
   virtual void visit(FirstElement&) = 0;
   virtual void visit(SecondElement&) = 0;
   virtual void visit(ThirdElement&) = 0;
};
```

instead of defining it something like:-

```
struct AbstractVisitor{
   virtual void visit(AbstractElement&) = 0;
};
```

Is there any gain in defining the class the way writer has defined it?

Comment: How would the double dispatch work in the scenario, do you reckon? How will the visitor know the dynamic type of the element?

Comment: See the results of searching for [**double dispatch** in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+double+dispatch). None stands out as a duplicate for me. Hopfully you get an answer that adequately explains what it is and how they are used in the visitor pattern.

Comment: The three different `visit` is exactly where you decide what different stuff you do. If it were an abstract base, all you have to work with is just `accept`, which doesn't help. It's just in this particular case the they don't need differential treatment

Comment: I can understand the use of having separate visitor function for all the individual classes when they are doing different stuffs. But here in this case all the individual visitor functions were just calling another function which accepts the parameter as a reference to abstract base class element.

Comment: @DineshMaurya - How is the visitor as implemented going to do something to a class based on the type of the visited element without having a separate function for each type?